# What date format is this ? (SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob)

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, time, format

I am making a small program and it uses `WMI`. There is a value which is, supposedly, a date and time. The value appears to be:

```
"20140221163958.621000+330".
```

Can anyone tell me which format is this and how to convert this to normal readable `DateAndTime`.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess, I would say it is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. The part after the dot I'm stumped on.

Comment: That was my first thought :) But what's the +330 (Timezome) doing there? And what's with the "." ;)

Comment: the format is `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.US+TZ`, meaning [4-digit year][2-digit month][2-digit day][2-digit hour][2-digit minute][2-digit second].[nanoseconds]+[time zone]. no idea how to translate it, but maybe that will get you closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official TechNet article regarding the timestamp format for WMI queries:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156576.aspx

Witch as it so happens gives a nice example in VB:

```
dtmInstallDate = "20140221163958.621000+330"

WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmInstallDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
 Mid(dtmInstallDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmInstallDate, 4) _
     & " " & Mid (dtmInstallDate, 9, 2) & ":" & _
         Mid(dtmInstallDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmInstallDate, _
             13, 2))

' would produce "2/21/14 4:39:58 PM"
```

Comment: That's the EXACT same article I was looking at.

Comment: @CoderGuy Does this answer your question, then?

Comment: Another Way in System.Management.dll is ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime("20140221163958.621000+330") would give the proper Date structure

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
   SELECT
    SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4) as year,SUBSTRING(date, 5, 2) as month,
    SUBSTRING(date, 7, 2) as day,SUBSTRING(date, 9, 2) as hours,
    SUBSTRING(date, 11, 2) as minutes,SUBSTRING(date, 13, 2) as seconds
  FROM
  table1
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91103/6)

if you want update your table and change this column use this

```
  Update table1 set date = 
    concat(SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4),' ',SUBSTRING(date, 5, 2),' ', 
    SUBSTRING(date, 7, 2),' ',SUBSTRING(date, 9, 2),':',
    SUBSTRING(date, 11, 2),':',SUBSTRING(date, 13, 2))
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91103/6)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search showed that it is the Standard Windows Format (UTC) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370(v=vs.85).aspx for more reference). To Convert it, I used a simple function.

```
Private Function ConvertToDateTime(ByVal in As String) As String

    Return CDate(Mid(inDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
 Mid(inDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(inDate, 4) _
     & " " & Mid(inDate, 9, 2) & ":" & _
         Mid(inDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(inDate, _
             13, 2))

End Function
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156576.aspx